# jasper report how to print data as per users time zone

Tags: timezone, jasper-reports

Could someone please help me out on printing data as per user timezone. We have a scenario where the user will pass the timezone and based upon that the value should return. I found the way to modify the date parameters as per user passed time zone and get the result from database. But after that how should I write the data in there time zone. Do I need to convert individual date columns to be printed on there time zone or any other way is there to convert once as per there time zone and print all values.

Let me tell you we trying to implement this on existing reports, so we are looking for a process for least changes.

Please find the source code for a sample report.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2017-02-27T18:40:31 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TimeZoneQuery" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="842" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="6af36fbc-520f-436a-a8b5-1510d55e7474">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <style name="column header" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#D2D2D2" fill="Solid" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="Tahoma" fontSize="11" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#979991"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#979991"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#979991"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#979991"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="detail" forecolor="#000000" fill="Solid" vTextAlign="Middle" vImageAlign="Middle" fontName="Tahoma" fontSize="11" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#979991"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#979991"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#979991"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#979991"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <parameter name="FromDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="ToDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="userTimezone" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="FromDateTZ" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["'"+$P{REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY}.createDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",$P{REPORT_LOCALE}, java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone($P{userTimezone})).format(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse($P{FromDate}+" 00:00:00'"))+"'"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="ToDateTZ" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["'"+$P{REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY}.createDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",$P{REPORT_LOCALE}, java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone($P{userTimezone})).format(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse($P{ToDate}+" 00:00:00'"))+"'"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="PrintTZ" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_TIME_ZONE}.getTimeZone($P{userTimezone})]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select job.transcribed_date::text,job.created_Date::text, job.delivered_date::text,job.JOB_ID, job.client_facility_iD,job.DICTATION_LENGTH
from DW.job_f job 
where job.transcribed_date between to_timestamp( $P!{FromDateTZ} ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and to_timestamp( $P!{ToDateTZ}  ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="transcribed_date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="created_date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="delivered_date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="job_id" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="client_facility_id" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="dictation_length" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="120" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="842" height="30" uuid="68bf2fd7-6d2a-4101-aa84-2f1dc73aa782"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Report Header Section"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="842" height="20" uuid="7e08b87a-bfd3-4c97-85c2-0495253e1ee9"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma" size="10" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Time Run : "+new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="842" height="20" uuid="d6500562-18ff-4426-b997-c928ea4fac7f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Report Description"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="842" height="20" uuid="5ac7e312-67d6-4cb5-b140-db61aec3a23e"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="422" height="30" uuid="9c55c0f6-3bdd-4a6e-89ea-c68f35afde77"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Date Between "+$P{FromDateTZ} +"  and  "+$P{ToDateTZ}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="422" y="70" width="420" height="30" uuid="a3f557b3-cd79-42b6-b5b4-ab1d959edb3f"/>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="422" y="70" width="280" height="30" uuid="a6716a87-4ac6-469a-9340-808348561b83"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_TIME_ZONE}.toString()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" uuid="8f70b2ad-ad64-4bef-8d7e-fd35dcf761dc">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_TIME_ZONE}.getTimeZone($P{userTimezone})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="column header" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="142" height="30" uuid="47351e64-0eed-4b3f-8e65-bbd4aa71707b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["transcribed_date"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="column header" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="142" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="5b44c994-90f9-4861-9dbd-37b0f2a4325f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["created_date"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="column header" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="282" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="118a7ea2-1a87-46ad-887b-9258ac5b39f5"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["delivered_date"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="column header" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="422" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="16275c85-468f-4f0f-bc11-56741eca0c01"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["job_id"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="column header" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="562" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="60ba0fee-da2a-40d1-9a15-c7dd6a699e6d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["client_facility_id"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="column header" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="702" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="7e7b7403-55d3-4414-b9a5-f55e9a4503c3"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["dictation_length"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="detail" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="142" height="30" uuid="ac7dc00e-7886-4ada-84f2-a626739b4390">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{transcribed_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="detail" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="142" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="58f2d24f-451d-429b-a6ba-adf3b6095093"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{created_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="detail" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="282" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="256ad4fb-2886-4368-8097-635c2991064d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{delivered_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="detail" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="422" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="2beac647-69e2-4fb6-bbe2-9a9730038a56"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{job_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="detail" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="562" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="a88d32dd-1cc3-4bdc-9ef9-540b022377c9"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{client_facility_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="detail" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="702" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="82fb777d-e46f-448f-a4c5-dab3b9ca0b3f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dictation_length}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        </band>
    </summary>
    <noData>
        <band height="40">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="842" height="40" uuid="2de331a1-b95b-4154-99f7-095e5cade32c"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Tahoma" size="11" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[No Results
    The specified criteria didn't result in any data. This is often caused by applying filters and/or selections that are too restrictive or that contain incorrect values. Please check your Analysis Filters and try again. ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </noData>
</jasperReport>
```

If you see this is build for accepting three parameters. Two date fields and one users timezone prompt. Based upon the date filter provided I'm converting the those to users time zone format and passing that to the database. The issue is while printing the result on there timezone. As my report has three date time fields which should display the result also as per there user timezone.

My question is there any way I can fix the timezone at the top of the report instead of converting all the three date time fields individually. Let me know if you need more clarification on this. Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should post the sample and illustrate the problem

Comment: I just added the sample code on top. please have a look.

Comment: Its not about a single report. We have around 500 different format of jrxml and we were following MM-DD-YYYY date pattern. Now while shifting the templates to Jasper server we are seeing its passing date pattern as YYYY-MM-DD to the report templates. I was asking is there a configuration in jasper server 7.1 where we can implement the pattern we want instead of changing all the jrxml's individually.